# Lua (And SQL) Error, attempt to call a boolean value

Tags: sql, lua, garrys-mod

So I'm getting this error while making an addon for Garrys mod, I've been trying for a while but can't quite figure this error out:

> [ERROR] addons/ted_stockmarket/lua/autorun/server/stockmarket_init.lua:6: attempt to call a boolean value
>       1. loadcompany - addons/ted_stockmarket/lua/autorun/server/stockmarket_init.lua:6
>       2. unknown - addons/ted_stockmarket/lua/autorun/server/stockmarket_init.lua:20
>       3. unknown - lua/includes/modules/concommand.lua:54

Files are included in full so line numbers will be exact, doing on pastebin because I can't figure out the formatting on this right now. The code is kind of all over the place, I haven't touched this is a while and half of the stuff in the file is bound to be replaced

```
include("stockmarketprices.lua")
include("stockmarket_config.lua")

local function loadcompany(cmp)

if cmp != nil and sql.TableExists("stockmarket_sharedata") then sql.Query("INSERT INTO stockmarket_sharedata (Companyshort, Company, Shares, Value) VALUES ('"..cmp[2]..", "..cmp[3]..", "..cmp[4]..", "..cmp[5])"')"


end
end

local function test()

    if !sql.TableExists(stockmarket_sharedata) then
        print("Stock market performing initial load...")
        sql.Query( "CREATE TABLE stockmarket_sharedata ( Companyshort string not null, Company string not null, Shares string not null, Value int not null, Rate decimal not null)" )

        print("Stock market done loading, restart your server to apply changes.")
    end
    if stock1[1] == 1 then loadcompany(stock1)
        print(stock1[3].." is done loading!")
        end
end
hook.Add("Initialize", "First Load", test)

function sharepricechange(shortname, chance, low, high, direction)
if math.random(1, 100) <= chance then shortname.marketbump = math.random(low, high) end


end



hook.Add( "PlayerSay", "chatcommands", function( ply, text )
    local text = string.lower( text )
    local amount = tonumber(string.sub(text, 16))
    local shares = tonumber(file.Read("stockmarket/lifeinsuranceshrs.txt"))

        if  string.sub(text, 1, 14) == "/buyshares ins" and amount <= shares then
            file.Write("stockmarket/lifeinsuranceshrs.txt", ((tonumber(file.Read("stockmarket/lifeinsuranceshrs.txt"))) - tonumber(string.sub(text, 16))))
            print("You have invested! There are now "..file.Read("stockmarket/lifeinsuranceshrs.txt").. " shares left for life insurance")
        else end

        if text == "/stockmarkethelp" then
            ply:PrintMessage(HUD_PRINTCONSOLE, [[ /buyshares "company" "amount" - Purchase a specified amount of shares from a specified company.
            /stockmarket - Prints all information about the stock market in console.]])
        return("") end

end)

function ResetStockmarket(ply)
if ply:IsUserGroup("superadmin") then
local files, directories = file.Find( "*", "DATA")
print(files[1])
file.Delete("stockmarket")end
if !ply:IsUserGroup("superadmin") then ply:PrintMessage( HUD_PRINTCONSOLE, "You are not the right rank to use this command" )
end
end

concommand.Add( "stockmarket_reset", ResetStockmarket)
concommand.Add( "stockmarket_test", test)
```

pastebin.com/ERFfnbMc

```
stock1 = { -- DO NOT CHANGE THE TABLE IDENTIFIER
1, -- First line, determine whether or not you want this company to work
"FLN", -- The shortname of the company, keep 3 letters for consistency
"Flynn's Funerals", -- The name of the company
10000, -- The default amount of shares avaliable
94, -- The starting price of each share
0 -- The rate of the shares change in value, do not touch this.
}
```

pastebin.com/jbJseUWC

Comment: You have some problems with syntax. Lua's "not equal" operator is written as `~=`, and not as `!=`. Also, boolean negation expressed as operator `not`, and not with exclamation mark in front of function call. Fix those first.

Comment: @Vlad - garrys-mod has modified Lua with enhanced syntax.  Yes, exclamation mark means boolean negation.

Comment: Ah, didn't know about that additions to syntax...

Comment: You have incorrect both Lua and SQL: replace `VALUES ('"..cmp[2]..", "..cmp[3]..", "..cmp[4]..", "..cmp[5])"')"` with `VALUES ('"..cmp[2].."', '"..cmp[3].."', "..cmp[4]..", "..cmp[5]..")")`.  And `Flynn's Funerals` should have inner `'` escaped somehow (probably by doubling it?  Use `cmp[3]:gsub("'", "''")` for doubling)

Comment: Please dont use pastebin just add your code to your question.